# How to find the largest squares that can be used to tile a rectangular sheet of paper?

Tags: c, algorithm, math

Given the length and breadth of a sheet of paper, we have to divide the sheet into squares of equal sizes.  We want to find the number of squares the paper would be cut into if we cut it into squares of this maximum length.

I have the following  code.  Is this code correct?

```
main()
{
int t,l,b,i,j,area;
scanf("%d",&t);
int a[t];
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    a[i]=0;
    scanf("%d%d",&l,&b);
    area=l*b;
    for(j=1;j*j<=area;j++)
    {
        if(area%(j*j) ==0)
            a[i]=area/(j*j);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Use meaningful variable names, I beg you!

Comment: and put spaces around those operators.

Comment: No, what you have is not correct. Consider an 1×4 rectangle. You'd choose a 2×2 square.

Comment: What on earth does "the no f squares cut wid d maximum length" mean?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson U n0 kan txtsp34k?

Comment: Not going to invest the effort to "txtsp34k", thank you very much. There's plenty of other things to be doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a hint, if the length and breadth are integers, then the largest square size you can use will be given by the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of the length and the breadth, since the square size has to divide the length and breadth.  Try using [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to compute their GCD; it's very easy to code up and extremely efficient.

You can then determine the number of squares by computing

```
length * breadth / gcd(length, breadth)^2
```

The numerator is the total area of the paper, and the denominator is the total area of one square.

Hope this helps!